# SQL Server : even I used 'In' the subquery returned more than 1 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Since yesterday I am stuck with this request, it returns an error when hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID equal to 3 or 4. But when my field equals 1 or 2 it works.

```
hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 1 ====> su.UNITKEY equals  3 or 4
hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 2 ====> su.UNITKEY equals   9 or 10
hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 3 ====> su.UNITKEY equals   12
hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 4 ====> su.UNITKEY equals   13 or 14
```

And here is the error:

> The subquery returned more than  1 values. This is not allowed when the subquery follows =,! =, <, <=,>,> = Or when it is used as an expression.

Thanks for your help

```
select c.[HISTORYNUMBER]
      ,c.[NAMECUSTOMER]
      ,c.[FIRSTSURNAMECUSTOMER]
      --,c.[SECONDSURNAMECUSTOMER] 
      ,ts.DESCRIPTION as Genre
      ,convert(date,c.[DATEBIRTH],103) as 'Date de naissance'
      ,c.[ADDRESS]
      ,a.[ENTITY]
      ,s.SPECIALTYDESCRIPTION
      ,su.DESCRIPTION as Unité
      ,hs.HOSPITALIZATIONDATE
     ,hs.OUTPUTDATE
     ,hs.MOVEMSPECIALITYID
      from HealthcareProcs..HospProcess hs
inner join PatientManagement..Customer c
on c.CUSTOMERID = hs.CUSTOMERID
inner join Configuration..agreement a
on hs.AGREEMENTID = a.[KEY]
inner join Configuration..specialty s
on s.[KEY] = hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID
left join configuration..SpecialtyUnits su
on  su.SPECIALTY = s.[KEY]
inner join Configuration..Hospitalspecialty hsp
on hsp.SPECIALITYID = s.[KEY]
inner join configuration..tables ts
on ts.[KEY] = c.GENDER
and ts.[TABLE] = 'EstGenero'

where hs.outputdate is null 
and hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID in (3)
and hs.ENTRYID is not null
--and hospitalizationdate >= @datedebut + ' 00:00:00'
--and hospitalizationdate <=  @datefin+ ' 23:59:59'
--and hsp.HEALTHCENTREID = @centre
and su.UNITKEY in (12)

and c.GENDER in (case 
                when (su.UNITKEY = 4 or su.UNITKEY = 10) and (hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 1 or hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 2) then 0   
                when (su.UNITKEY = 3 or su.UNITKEY = 9) and (hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 1 or hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 2) then 1 
                when (su.UNITKEY in (3,4) or su.UNITKEY in (9,10) ) and (hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 1 or hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 2) then (select distinct gender from PatientManagement..Customer where GENDER in (0,1))
                when hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 3 then (select [key] from configuration..tables ts where  ts.[TABLE] = 'EstGenero')
                when hs.HOSPITALIZESPECIALTYID = 4 and su.UNITKEY in (13,14) then (select [key] from configuration..tables ts where  ts.[TABLE] = 'EstGenero')
                    end)
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I am pretty sure that you can't use your gender cpmparison as you did: GENDER in (CASE WHEN... THEN [subselect]). Why don't you build a cte first and join it in your query? This way you won't need the comparison against a subselect.

Comment: What Farz and  Tyron78 is trying to tell you is that while you are using an IN clause which supports subqueries that return multiple values, the CASE statement you are using within your IN clause will only accept a subquery that returns a single value.

Comment: Your case expression is a disaster of epic proportions. The third predicate is unreachable because the first or second would have already fired. Not sure why you are using multiple IN expressions on the same column. Lucky for you because then you select the gender from your customer table which would return more than 1 row. I am going out on a limb here but since it seems that gender is always 0, 1 in all of your tables couldn't you replace this whole monstrous case expression with c.GENDER in (0, 1)???

Answer (score 1):

Do either of these queries return more than one value?

```
select distinct gender from PatientManagement..Customer where GENDER in (0,1)

select [key] from configuration..tables ts where  ts.[TABLE] = 'EstGenero'
```

Since when your fields are 1 or 2 it works, I think the second query is the one returning more than one value.

Comment: I already tested this option, I used the first query :     <code>select distinct gender from PatientManagement..Customer where GENDER in (0,1)</code>
     it returns me the same error

Comment: @almaje this is where your problem is. The point is, one of the three subqueries in your CASE statement are returning more than one value.